# Geometrical extraction from Step file

Tags: file, step

Can anyone help me the proceedure how to extract geometrical data from the Step file in python? I have already tried but the no result.
 Thank you

Comment: Which Application Protocol of STEP? Did you take a look at pythonOCC?

Comment: Appication protocol 214

Comment: An option is to use Freecad, it has an API that allows call some of the functions in a python scritp.